# Merge coverage report from multiple tests

Tags: dart, coveralls

I have a repository that contains three components, fronted, backend and mobile app (flutter). Each of these are in their own package and have their own tests

```
frontend/pubspec.yaml
frontend/packages
frontend/lib/src
frontend/test/test_frontend.dart
backend/pubspec.yaml
backend/packages
backend/lib/src
backend/test/test_backend.dart
mobile/pubspec.yaml
mobile/packages
mobile/lib/src
mobile/test/test_mobile.dart
run_tests.sh
```

I use [dart_coveralls](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_coveralls) to calculate code coverage and can easily get separate report for each of the components

```
pub global run dart_coveralls report test/test_frontend.dart
```

However I would like to get one merged report for the entire repository containing frontend, backend and mobile components in one. I have discovered no way to actually do this, the following does generate a combined report but it is faulty and no coverage is actually included.

```
pushd frontend
dart --observe=12345 test/test_frontend.dart &
pub global run coverage:collect_coverage --port=12345 -o ../cov/frontend.json --resume-isolates
popd
pushd backend
dart --observe=12345 test/test_backend.dart &
pub global run coverage:collect_coverage --port=12345 -o ../cov/backend.json --resume-isolates
popd
pub global run dart_coveralls upload --token <secret> --exclude-test-files cov
```

Is it somehow possible to get a combined coveralls report for multiple projects.

Comment: See also https://github.com/duse-io/dart-coveralls/issues/50